# Regex values inside curly brackets

Tags: java, regex

I have a random variable lets call it R inside a curly brackets like so:

```
{R}
```

I have tried to regex it with this:

```
{(.*?)//}
```

I then have this error

```
"Caused by: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: 
Syntax error U_REGEX_RULE_SYNTAX near index 1:"
```

Indicator targeting `{(.*?)} "("`

I tried doing it without the brackets same error. This time indicator targets `"."`

Could someone help me find an alternate solution to regex items inside a curly brackets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try escaping curly braces:

```
String regex = "\\{(.*?)\\}";
```

Answer (score 3):

Curly brackets are used in regexp to define specific sequence repetition.

you have to escape them in the regexp.

```
\{(.*?)\}
```

should work better

Answer (score 1):

Escape the {}s:

```
String regStr = "\\{.\\}";
```

I've found [this interactive regex testing page](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) useful in refining Java regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely clear what you are trying to do by

```
\{.*\}
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

You can escape special characters using a backslash `\`.  See [What special characters must be escaped in regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions) for more information (although there is no general rule).  Try escaping the curly braces `{}` and slashes `//`.